# Images for file extensions

Tags: image

I want the small images of different file formats (docx,ppt,txt etc.) to display along with the file names of corresponding type.

Any link to get these images?

TIA.

Comment: docx ,ppt , txt are documents ..

Comment: Yes I want icons for different file extensions esp for docx,pdf,ppt,xls :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a file list with the associated icons showing net to the file name in your program, you can use the [SHCreateFileExtractIcon Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762132(VS.85).aspx) from the shell extension of Windows. It extracts the associated icon for a given file.

```
HRESULT SHCreateFileExtractIcon(      
    LPCTSTR pszFile,
    DWORD dwFileAttributes,
    REFIID riid,
    void **ppv
```

If you want to have the exact icons that are associated with files at any time, this is the way to go. You could always store these icons you obtain to disc to come up with your own set of icons.